# Generate random array that is fixed - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have data that is currently in alphabetical order and I want it to be randomised which is simple enough...however I don't want it to be randomised every time the code is reloaded.

So for example I have `1,2,3,4,5,6` and the code makes the data output for example as `2,5,1,3,6,4` every single time. The actual data has 2500 entries if that makes any difference.

EDIT: In answer to my question being put on hold as 'too broad' - Too broad means there are TOO MANY possible answers to my question. Since there is only ***one answer*** so far and it seems there cannot be any others how can it be too broad...

Comment: Why not store the data in the randomized order in which you intend to use it?

Comment: Because it's more useful to keep it in alphabetical order and do the manipulation in code. It's not useful to keep the data file in a random order.

Comment: You could use `shuffle()`. To make it output the same values every single time when the page has been loaded, you need to store it in your database or JSON or YAML or whatever you like. Ask if the value exists, if not, use `shuffle()`.

Comment: @Reza Saadati I'm pretty sure shuffle will produce a different result every time the code is run....?

Comment: When shuffle() is not your need it is unclear what you want ....

Comment: @Hasen sure it will. That's why you need to store it somewhere as I mentioned.

Comment: @meagar or build a simple index of the data, shuffle and store that, and use that as a lookup for the "deterministic shuffle"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly seed the random number generator with the same value each time:

```
$list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
srand(123456);
shuffle($list);
print_r($list);
```

This will result in the same shuffle each time the script is run.

Why this works:

`array_shuffle()` uses the same random number generator that `rand()` does. If you do not manually seed that random number generator with `srand()`, PHP does it for you, with a random seed. Thus, if you simply call `array_shuffle()` or `rand()`, you get a different output every time. This is how it's almost always used.

Now, if you want ***reproduceable*** random results, you can use `srand()` to initialize the random number generator by manually [seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) it with a known value. As long as the random number generator is seeded with the same value, it will always produce the same results, even across different runs of the same script. Video games often use this technique (e.g., "Enter your game number") to allow you play the same random game over again.

It might help if you think of it this way: the computer doesn't give you a truly random number, it has billions of pre-built series of random numbers that are infinitely long. When you call `array_shuffle()` the computer picks one of those series for you. But if you precede that call with `srand(123456)`, then you're saying, "Whenever you need a random number, use series number 123456." The value you use doesn't matter, as long as it's the same each time you run the script.

Comment: This will fail unexpectedly on servers where `srand` is disabled by https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-srand-ignore. It's still the closest thing to a correct answer, so I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: I think you mean print_r($list); ? Your code doesn't work, the randomisation is different every time.

Comment: Oops, yes fixed. You likely have the aforementioned suhosin setting enabled. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Alex Howansky You're just doing a normal shuffle, that's how it works. It shuffles the result every time. I need it to make the same shuffle every time.

Comment: @Hasen No. If you seed with the same value first, shuffle will produce the same output. (Unless you have suhosin, as noted.)

Comment: Run this as many times as you like and the output will be the same: https://3v4l.org/IREBq

Comment: @Alex Howansky You're right it does work. Not sure why though. Can you explain it a bit more in your answer and I'll accept the answer. What does `srand(123456)` do for example? My actual code has 2500 entries - is this code gonna still work ok?

Comment: @Hasen http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php

Comment: @Hasen Updated with more details. The size of your array does not matter. However note that any other call to a function that needs a random number will "bump" the series and throw off your result, so I recommend calling `srand()` immediately before the shuffle, versus at the start of the script or class.

Comment: @Alex Howansky Thanks for your answer to my question, it's the perfect answer to my question. No idea why my question got so many down votes and people even reporting it as 'too broad'. There is only one answer to my question so if anything it's the opposite of broad.

Comment: @Hasen There are dozens of ways of answering your question, and they are each "better" than the other depending on your requirements.

Comment: @meagar Yes dozens and dozens, thousands and thousands. Care to give at least ONE as an example? Otherwise might be better to just edit out your comment..There are thousands and thousands of questions on stackoverflow that have 5-10 answers on them each but are not marked as 'too broad'. This one has just one answer.